# How to show alert after selecting listview jquery

Tags: jquery, ios, listview, jquery-mobile, alert

HI guys this is going to seem like the most stupid question ever possible but the site that was helping me go through this is undergoing maintanence. I am in the early stages of learning jquery mobile and need some help.

I have an ordered listview non-dynamic in a html5 page. I want to show an alert on the phone (like a pop up alert on ios) that says text to the user and they can then click ok to close it to go back to the ordered list view. My html is this. I would like it when i click on Montview from this list as an example a alert pops up on the iphone with some text for the user and they then click ok to close it.

Can someone help me with the jquery mobile javascript required, like i said i was learning but then the site went down.

Thanks

```
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="lib/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="src/css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="src/css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.1.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Grounds</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ol data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-inset="true">
                <li>
                    <a>Montview</a>
                </li>
                <li data-theme="b">
                    <a>Asquith</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Button</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Button</a>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content"></div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry If I misunderstood the question, but are you looking for something like this perhaps?

```
// this will bind all of the items
$(function(){
    $("ol[data-role='listview']").click(function(){
        alert("woah!");
    });
});
```

EDIT:
If you want to bind a different event for each list item you need to give the items an id (or something to distinguish them by, you could also possibly select each - go through their contents and distinguish them this way, however I would advise against this approach).

```
        <ol data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-inset="true">
            <li id="mountView">
                <a>Montview</a>
            </li>
            <li id="asquith" data-theme="b">
                <a>Asquith</a>
            </li>
            <li id="someButton">
                <a>Button</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>Button</a>
            </li>
        </ol>
```

Then in your javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("li#mountView").click(function(){
        alert("Mount View Event!!!");
    });

    $("li#asquith").click(function(){
        alert("Asquith Event!!!");
    });
});
```

**EDIT 2**

Upon inspecting your html closer, I've noticed that you've added another "page" section.
I suspect that you want open this page's content upon clicking one of the links.
Check this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nMR85/833/) and you'll know what I mean. (this solution doesn't even require code, jquery mobile will autowire your events provided that you've annotate your elements correctly). Notice this part -> `<a href="#page2" data-rel="dialog">bar</a>`

Comment: hi yes that sounds somewhat like what i need but the list view has multiple items and i want to choose the specific item. And show a different alert per item in the list.

Comment: so possibly $(function(){
$("#something").click(function(){
alert("woah");
 });
});

where ive given the li item an id of something like so?  
<li id="something">

Hope taht sort of gives you an idea of what i am looking for.

Comment: Somewhat related but even this isn't working in my browser (Google Chrome) so maybe jquery is busted as well for me, how do i fix it? :|

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     $( document ).ready( function() {
 $("a").click(function( event ) {
    alert("Thanks for visiting!")
});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: i managed to figure it out myself :) was setting the id incorrectly in the listview.

Comment: Check my second edit (and the jsfiddle, it's another option).

Comment: oh brilliant, exactly what i wanted

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I've given you another link in the fiddle (the older one, forgot to update it) -> check it once more (click on "bar"), it's different behavior. Also, please feel free to accept this as an answer if it's what you're looking for :)))